# Publishing Web Service returns Unable to build data connection: No route to host (425)

Tags: visual-studio, c#, web-services

I wrote my Web Service and now want to host it on my Ubuntu 16.04 WebServer.
But at some time I get 
`Unable to build data connection: No route to host (425)` Error.

How can I fix this problem? If I want to connect to my WebServer via FTP and WinSCP I use following ConnectionData.

Server: myserver.de | user: myuser | password: mypass | port: 21
But in Visual Studio I have to connect like:
Server: myserver.de | websitepath: www/WebService (So it will create WebService file) rest is normal.

And VS tries to connect to `ftp://myserver.de/www/WebService` instead of `ftp://myserver.de`.

But If i remove the `www/WebService` I will get `550 Permission Denied` Error because I have no rights to create folder in `/` dir where `www` etc. is located.

Comment: What does it mean *"at some time"*? Do you get the problem only sometimes?

Comment: Did you keep default *"Connect using passive mode"*?